# Bash -o operator

Tags: bash

I am trying to use a bash script to delete directories on user log out. Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == "user1" -o $1 == "user2" -o $1 == "user3" ]]; then
      exit 0

rm -r /Users/$1
fi
```

Each time I run this script interactively, I get a syntax error. Unexpected expression near "-o". I am a bit stumped. The goal of the script is to delete all directories except user1, user2 and user3. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: `-o` *isn't* a bash operator; it's a `test` operator. `[ ]` is a way to call the `test` command; `[[ ]]`, by contrast, is bash syntax, and uses bash's own operators.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-o` is not supported by the conditional expression command. Use `||` instead:

```
if [[ $1 == "user1" || $1 == "user2" || $1 == "user3" ]]; then
```

(As an aside, `-o` isn't recommended for use with the `test`/`[` command, either. Instead of

```
if [ "$1" = "user1" -o "$1" = "user2" ]; then
```

the recommended sequence is

```
if [ "$1" = "user1" ] || [ "$1" = "user2" ]; then
```

i.e., use two separate calls to `test`/`[` joined by `||`.

Comment: Thanks. The script no longer errors with the changed syntax (||), but it doesn't remove the extra user directories either.

Comment: Well, you are calling `exit` before you call `rm`.

Comment: I took the "exit 0" out and the script still won't delete the directories.

Comment: That's a separate issue from the posted question, involving the value of `$1` when the `if` statement is run.